# Changing .text to .html

Tags: jquery

Simple question I think for someone that knows what they're doing, but I'm still learning scripting...

I have this line of script which replaces the text on a button when clicked:

```
btn.find('span').text('SHOW LESS');
```

But now I need it to change the html attributes of whats in the span. I thought it would be something like this:

```
btn.find('span').html('<span class="cbh-showMore" aria-hidden="true">SHOW LESS</span>');
```

...but its adding a span within the span. I need it to change the existing span.

Could someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your desired result and what are the original <span> attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith` to replace the whole element with new HTML, rather than putting the span inside it.

```
btn.find('span').replaceWith('<span class="cbh-showMore" aria-hidden="true">SHOW LESS</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to change , not add then

```
 btn.find('span').addClass('cbh-showMore').attr("aria-hidden",true).html('SHOW LESS');
```

Comment: The original `<span>` might not contain *SHOW LESS* as its text

Comment: oh yah forgot about the SHOW LESS, I added it.